# Virtualbox seamless mode in Bodhi Linux

Tags: virtualbox, bodhi

I just created a Bodhi virtual machine (Win 7 Host) and installed virtualbox-guest-additions but I'm still not able to activate seamless mode in virtualbox.
Is this mode even supported for Bodhi Linux and what do I need to add to my guest system?
My goal is to integrate Bodhi terminal sessions into my Windows Desktop without the Bodhi Desktop.
The seamless mode isn't available means I'm not able to click on that tab.
`/etc/init.d/vboxadd` isn't on my machine, only `/etc/init.d/virtualbox`

Comment: can you post the output of following:
/etc/init.d/vboxadd setup

Comment: What error message do you have?

Comment: By default, compositing is turned off in Bodhi, and I would imagine that you need it on. Try that maybe. (backup your `~/.e` directory first just in case)

Comment: So I'm assuming that /etc/init.d/virtualbox setup does compiles all the necessary modules without any error correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about VirtualBox. You should ask this question on SuperUser SE.

Answer (score 3):

I've installed Bodhi under Virtual Box 4.2.6 with the corresponding VirtualBox Extensions.

Since you don't have the /etc/init.d/vboxadd then I guess you are using Virtual Box 4.1 or earlier. Either upgrade the VirtualBox to 4.2.6 or maybe you are missing the VirtualBox extensions for your installed version
I'll put the steps that I performed according to VirtualBox 4.2.6

```
mount /dev/cdrom
cd /cdrom; ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

during this process it will complain about gcc not found

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gcc
/etc/init.t/vboxadd setup
```

After this restart X and it will be working.